# How to display error message on login page and not render an exception

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am using the UserChecker class to test the activation of an account ,I am using the following code ,but I want to display a message account not activated on the login page not throwing an exception:

```
Class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
  public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
  {
     if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
        return;
    }

   }

   public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
   {
    if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
        return;
    }

    if (!$user->getIsActive()) {
        throw new \Exception("member not active");
    }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\LockedException;

Class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        //.....
    }
    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->getIsActive()) {
            $ex = new LockedException("member not active");
            $ex->setUser($user);
            throw $ex;
        }

    }
}
```

I am not sure about your Symfony version.